# TypeScript: is there something like __FILE__ compiler macro?

Tags: typescript

From other languages I know `__FILE__` or similar expressions (for instance: in PHP a constant, in C a preprocessor macro) that are replaced with the current source file path. Is there anything like this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a node application

```
__dirname
```

Will give you the current module directory path

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not a Node app. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently feature request for that, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4892

From what I am seeing it is not implemented yet.

One work-around can be, adding your custom comments( for example /** @compile-if */) and then using Gulp/Grunt task to transform code after actual Typescript compilation.

Comment: Too bad. I asked because I hoped I could avoid having to build a home-made solution for this. Doesn’t look like I can.